# PHP XML file appending

Tags: php, xml

Here's my code:

```
public function write($txt){
              $randID = rand();
              $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
              $doc->formatOutput = true; 
              $doc->load($this->fileName); 
              $b = $doc->createElement( "input"); 
              $id = $doc->createElement( "id",$randID); 
              $b->appendChild($id);

              $text = $doc->createElement( "text",$txt); 
              $b->appendChild( $text ); 
              $doc->appendChild($b); 

              $doc->save($this->fileName); 

        }
```

Why does this code always overwrite the old file? Why doesn't it append to the end of the existing file? I'm new to XML with PHP :)

Comment: You are opening `new DomDocument()` rather than existing one with [`DomDocument::load()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.load.php)

Comment: Can you give an example of the file a) before you call the script, b) after the script is finished and c) the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because it just loads the file in memory, than adds the xml you want and than saves it to disk.

Because you use the *same filename* while saving, it overwrites the original file with a new file containing all XML, including the new elements and data. Makes sense to me.